# Why while loop don't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text in a single line (white-space: nowrap).
I want to reduce the font size of this text if the width of it greater than the width of the parent-block.

I use while loop. Why it doesn't work? Width of "elemWidth" is not updated and loop and the cycle freeze?

```
$('.slider__title-wrap').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var fontSize = 50;
    var elem = $(this).find('.slider__title');
    var elemWidth = elem.width();

    while(elemWidth >= width) {
        fontSize = Math.floor(fontSize * 0.96);
        elem.css({fontSize: fontSize+'px'});
    };
})
```

Comment: You don't seem to be changing either `elemWidth` or `width` inside the `while` loop. So it will either never start, or never end.

Comment: You dont need a `while` here. You need an active listener for size change

Comment: When reducing the font-size of the elemWidth it width changes (inline-block), but in the loop width don't changes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elemWidth = elem.width();
```

makes a copy of `elem.width();`

You need to reevaluate `elemWidth` into your loop :

```
$('.slider__title-wrap').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var fontSize = 50;
    var elem = $(this).find('.slider__title');
    var elemWidth = elem.width();

    while(elemWidth >= width) {
        fontSize = Math.floor(fontSize * 0.96);
        elem.css({fontSize: fontSize+'px'});
        elemWidth = elem.width();
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be changing either `elemWidth` or `width` inside the `while` loop. So it will either never start, or never end. You need to update the values you're comparing before the loop ends:

```
$('.slider__title-wrap').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var fontSize = 50;
    var elem = $(this).find('.slider__title');
    var elemWidth = elem.width();

    while(elemWidth >= width) {
        fontSize = Math.floor(fontSize * 0.96);
        elem.css({fontSize: fontSize+'px'});
        width = $(this).width();
        elemWidth = $(this).find('.slider__title').width();
    };
});
```

Alternatively, eliminate the variables so you don't have to update anything:

```
$('.slider__title-wrap').each(function(){
    var fontSize = 50;

    while($(this).width() >= $(this).find('.slider__title').width()) {
        fontSize = Math.floor(fontSize * 0.96);
        elem.css({fontSize: fontSize+'px'});
    };
});
```

Incidentally, I'd use `fontSize = fontSize-1;` instead of multiplying by `0.96`, but it's probably a micro-optimization.